# Activation before proper Deactivation WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my app I allow the user to go to the marketplace for various reasons. While loading the marketplace, if the user hits the back button very quickly it will try to go back to my apps saved stated. All my data from iso-storage etc is loaded just fine, but the screen is frozen. I have different application bars for various pivot items and as I do the swiping motion, I see the application bar changing, so I know the app is responsive.

The main problem is that the screen is stuck where the user initially launched the marketplace task. I understand that int this edge case, my App and Page constructors are not firing, and the events that are firing are on navigated from, application deactivated, application activated, and on navigated to.

I thought I could use a Boolean to basically cover the case for when a marketplace task has fired so that way I can reload the data context in the on navigated to method and set it to my view model. The screen however is still frozen.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Edit: Here is some relevant code

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    }

    DetermineIsTrial();
}

private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (playerController.chapterPlayer != null)
    {
        var store = new PersistentDataStorage();
        store.Backup(StringResource.ChapterPosition, playerController.chapterPlayer.Position);
        store.Backup(StringResource.ChapterUriString, playerController.chapterPlayer.Source.OriginalString);
        store.Backup(StringResource.NaturalDuration, playerController.chapterPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);
    }
}
```

Main Page XAML:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    App.viewIdentifier = StringResource.MainPageView;

    if (App.firstTimeLoading == false && PivotBackground.SelectedItem != SuggestedPivotItem)
    {
        BuildApplicationBar();
    }
    else if (PivotBackground.SelectedItem == SuggestedPivotItem)
    {
        BuildMarketPlaceApplicationBar();
    }

    if (App.firstTimeLoading == true)
    {
        BuildApplicationBar(); //builds the application bar

        //Restore the state from tombstone and set the audioplayer.
        App.playerController = new PlayerButtonsController();
        App.playerController.SetMediaPlayer(App.MainAudioPlayer);
        RestoreState();
        ResourceDictionary appResourceList = App.Current.Resources;
        App.firstTimeLoading = false;
        //default source for chapter position
        App.AudioMgr.SetChapterSource(0);
    }
}
```

More methods:

```
private void RestoreState()
{
    var store = new PersistentDataStorage();
    playerWasWhere = store.Restore<TimeSpan>(StringResource.ChapterPosition);
    naturalDuration = store.Restore<TimeSpan>(StringResource.NaturalDuration);
    currentAudioFile = store.Restore<String>(StringResource.ChapterUriString);
    SetAudioListScrollPosition();
    App.playerController.SetPositionFromIsoStorage(currentAudioFile, playerWasWhere, naturalDuration);
}

public void LoadData()
{

    CreateAudioPlayerGUIfromChapterList();
    CreateAboutMenuGUIfromExtrasData();
    CreateQuotesMenuGUIfromExtrasData();
    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
}

private void CreateAudioPlayerGUIfromChapterList()
{
    int numberOfChapters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < App.AudioMgr.Parts.Count; i++)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> tempObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        for (int j = 0; j < App.AudioMgr.Parts[i].NumberOfChapters; j++)
        {
            tempObservableCollection.Add(new ItemViewModel()
            {
                LineOne = ProcessTitle(App.AudioMgr.Chapters[numberOfChapters + j].Title),
                LineTwo = App.AudioMgr.Chapters[numberOfChapters + j].StatusMessage,
                ItemAlpha = 0.0,
                ChapterForeground = ChapterInfo.StatusColor[(int)App.AudioMgr.Chapters[numberOfChapters + j].Status],
                Progress = 0,
                Width = 0,
                UserColorTheme = App.accentBrush,
                PlayIconVisible = Visibility.Collapsed,
                ChapterDurationProgressBarAdjacent = StringResource.Space,
                ContainingPart = i,
                MediaStateImageSource = StringResource.KJIcons + App.themeDir + StringResource.AppBarSpeaker
            });
        }
        numberOfChapters += App.AudioMgr.Parts[i].NumberOfChapters;

        //no parts header doesn't need spacing or border since its the first header.
        if (i == 0 && App.AudioMgr.Parts[i].Title == "")
        {
            Parts.Add(new PartsViewModel()
            {
                PartsHeader = StringResource.Space,
                ChapterForeground = App.defaultForeground,
                ChaptersInPart = tempObservableCollection,
                PartsBackgroundBrush = App.partsBackgroundBrush,
                PartsHeaderHeight = 0,
                PartsBorderThickness = new Thickness(0)
            });
        }
        //parts header needs spacing and border
        else if (App.AudioMgr.Parts[i].Title != "")
        {
            Parts.Add(new PartsViewModel()
            {
                PartsHeader = App.AudioMgr.Parts[i].Title,
                ChapterForeground = App.defaultForeground,
                ChaptersInPart = tempObservableCollection,
                PartsBackgroundBrush = App.partsBackgroundBrush,
                PartsHeaderHeight = double.NaN,
                PartsBorderThickness = new Thickness(0,0,0,2)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Parts.Add(new PartsViewModel()
            {
                PartsHeader = StringResource.Space,
                ChapterForeground = App.defaultForeground,
                ChaptersInPart = tempObservableCollection,
                PartsBackgroundBrush = App.partsBackgroundBrush,
                PartsHeaderHeight = 0,
                PartsBorderThickness = new Thickness(0)
            });
        }
    }
}

private void CreateAboutMenuGUIfromExtrasData()
{
    int list_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            //Evaluate number of Authors
            case 0:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.AboutAuthorsArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                {
                    this.About.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.AboutAuthor }); //for one author
                }
                else if (list_count > 1)
                {
                    this.About.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.AboutAuthors }); //for more than one author
                }
                break;

             //Evaluate number of books (should only be one)
            case 1:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.AboutBookArrayList);
                if (list_count > 0)
                    this.About.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.AboutBook });
                break;

            //Evaluate number of Readers
            case 2:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.AboutNarratorsArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                {
                    this.About.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.AboutReader }); //for one reader
                }
                else if (list_count > 1)
                {
                    this.About.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.AboutReaders}); //for more than one reader
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void CreateQuotesMenuGUIfromExtrasData()
{
    int list_count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    {
        switch( i )
        {
            case 0:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesAuthorAboutArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesAboutAuthor});
                else if(list_count > 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesAboutAuthors });
                break;

            case 1:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesAuthorFromArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesFromAuthor });
                else if (list_count > 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesFromAuthors});
                break;

            case 2:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesBookAboutArrayList);
                if (list_count > 0)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesAboutBook });
                break;

            case 3:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesBookFromArrayList);
                if (list_count > 0)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesFromBook });
                break;

            case 4:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesReaderAboutArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesAboutReader });
                else if (list_count > 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesAboutReaders });
                break;

            case 5:
                list_count = DictionaryIterator(App.Parser.QuotesReaderFromArrayList);
                if (list_count == 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesFromReader });
                else if (list_count > 1)
                    this.Quotes.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = StringResource.QuotesFromReaders });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the LoadData method as well?

Comment: yeah give me a second, this one is pretty decently long

Comment: the load data basically is constructing everything the user sees

Comment: Which most likely is the problem!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, Where would I be loading the UI then?

Comment: Some point later in the execution chain. Anywhere that means you don't have to run a crazy amount of handling on the UI thread.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your help. I've had to edit this framework from someone else and you've definitely given some insight as to where all this stuff should be etc etc. So again, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately after moving stuff around, getting the ViewModel set up outside of the application activated event and into the onNavigatedTo event it still is freezing with the initial problem. The most interesting point though, is it isnt resetting this view model everytime since I have that check in there with the "isLoaded" boolean. So when it comes back from the task into the onNavigatedTo method it does nothing with the ViewModel (like it should) but it still freezes....Im kind of at a loss here

Comment: Try disable each of the Create methods, and after that, try disable more and more code, until you figure out what precisely is causing the issue, aka. old-fashion-debugging.

Comment: I've disabled almost the whole UI nothing is showing but the buttons that take me to the marketplace. I have disabled tombstoning, and it still gets stuck when I hit the back button quickly after activating the launcher task... This makes me belive that its not that my UI is too demanding or intensive...it has to be something else. Peter torr wrote an article on this very similar to my problem http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/12/11/how-to-correctly-handle-application-deactivation-and-reactivation.aspx

Comment: After more hours of trying to get this to work. I've come to the same conclusion, even with all my UI elements commented out, and tombstoning commented out. I still have a "frozen" pivot view. It will not swipe to different pivot items visually, but it will be on the different pivot items (again I can see this based on my application bar icons). Not really sure what the problem is here. Hopefully ill be lucky on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this happens because your code is locking up the UI thread. And the reason it locks it up, is because it's **way** to slow.

And looking at your code now, it's a *crazy* amount of work you're doing in what should be a simple data loading from the isolated storage. You need to move all this UI work over to the View, and first handle it upon creation of the actual view, not *before*, as you're doing right now.

Personally I dislike the idea of coupling the viewmodel with your App class, and I also think it's pointless to use the `Application_Activated/Deactivated` for tombstoning, rather than handling persistence at `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo`.

I think it'll be difficult to give a precise answer to what is causing the problem, but my guess right now lies in that you're using the process for the tombstoning to re-create the UI, instead of letting the UIThread itself do the work.

The whole part about you're generating the UI in C# is just so plain wrong as it can be. XAML is made for this, and it's *really* good at what it's made for.

Comment: What would be the difference then in this scenario. If I let the marketplaceDetail Task finish, and I hit the back button, everything is fine. The problem only occurs when I interrupt the task from finishing with the back button

Comment: So you're saying your app also freezes if you disable all your tombstoning code entirely?-)

Comment: I'm running that scenario now, basically just commented out ever loading the data from tombstoning, I'll see what happens in a second

Comment: Nope, I disabled my restoring state function and its perfectly fine still. So with tombstoning disabled it does what it is supposed to if I let the marketplace DetailTask finish

Comment: The main difference that is happening is when I let the task finish, then hit the back button (tombstoning or not) it runs the Application and Page constructors. When I interrupt the marketplace task with the back button the constructors don't fire. the answer has to lie in there somewhere.

Comment: No, the task isn't relevant, a fast home+back combo would do the same. Also, is this for Mango or not? Fast Application Start on Mango doesn't call the constructor upon return.

Comment: Generally how do you go about fixing this issue then? Because yes you are right, the same problem occurs with a rapid succession of start and back buttons. I know that windows wants to maintain that smoothness so they don't call the constructors. How should I try to manage these cases then?

Comment: In one of my apps where I had a identical problem, I decreased the amount of tombstoned data. So I think Matt Lacey is on the right track.

Comment: Well I am only tombstoning three things, 2 timespans and 1 string, i Don't think that this is too much of a problem?

Comment: By the sound of it, the problem could be that you're simply attempting to start some functionality with the audio that causes problem. If you could post the relevant code for where you handle the loading of the data, we could probably fix the issue.

Comment: The UI is all linked to XAML. these are all the bindings in the xaml to generate what I need so I'm not sure how I would change the way I created that. As for the UI work in the view. All the creation is in a viewmodel and I check to see upon startup if I even need to load it again with a simple (if App.ViewModel.isloaded) so I'm not redoing this everytime. I do agree that I can move the tombstoning to on navigated to and from though. I am still however confused with what you are saying about me using the tombstoning process to recreate the UI

Comment: Well, your code is a mess, so it's fairly difficult to see through what you're doing. I think it'll be difficult to give better advice than for you to profile what you're doing, and see if you can work out the performance issues. With the little amount of data you're persisting the Application Lifetime Service shouldn't be necessary at *all*. I personally never use it, and my UIs persists just fine :p

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're only restoring state if the code was actually tombstoned?

I suspect that you're coming back to your app before it is tombstoned but still trying to restore state. Quite what you're saving and how you restore it will determine how you can check if you need to restore it. Checking for null or if not the defautl value is probably the easiest way.
You may also get better performance if you only save the state of anything you absolutely have to. You should also try saving the State in the OnNavigatingFrom event, rather than the OnNavigatedFrom event.

What and how are you saving to IS?
Why not use the Page.State object?

Comment: I am saving three things to Isolated Storage. Since this application uses media elements, I am saving the audio file source that was playing, the position in the audio file, and the timespan of that audio file. I'm not saving the pages state at the moment

Comment: Saving a entire audiofile sounds expensive.

Comment: I also do have wrappers around the saving states, such as checking if things are null etc. And yes I am sure that the few things I am tombstoning are functioning properly

Comment: Im not saving an entire audio file, just the index

Comment: So that way I can load up the audio file again upon activation using that index to find the proper file

Comment: Sorry for possibly the noob question. But what would Page.State help me with here? I haven't used it before So I am unexperienced there, and I'm just tyring to follow your thought process

Comment: It wouldn't do much different. But using it rather than IsolatedStorage would definitively be encouraged, if your data isn't meant to be persisted between launches.

Comment: Ah, I need the data between launches though because I am workign with an audio book and its nice to have a "bookmark" of where you left off so that data is persistent

Comment: Page.State isn't persisted once you quit the application. Anyway, lets see some code!-)

Comment: Code should be posted, if you need to see more let me know, but this should be all the code involved with the tombstoning process

Comment: I asked if you were using IsolatedStorage over Page.State as if this was due to the size limits on `State` this may be a good indication of a possible issue.